# Problem with page not redirecting after submitting an HTML form and handling PUT request with FETCH API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api, put

I'm having a problem where the page won't redirect after submitting an HTML form and handling a PUT request. The issue I'm having involves a lot of code, so please ask clarifying questions about what certain things do. I will paste any code I feel may be relevant to my issue here.

Routing in `route.js` file:

```js
/* Profile Router */
router.route("/profile").get((req, res, next) => {
  Authorize.auth(req, res, next, "GET profile");
}, PagesController.getProfile);

/* Edit Profile Router */
router
  .route("/edit-profile")
  .get((req, res, next) => {
    Authorize.auth(req, res, next, "GET edit-profile");
  }, PagesController.getEditProfile)
  .put((req, res, next) => {
    Authorize.auth(req, res, next, "PUT edit-profile");
  }, PagesController.putEditProfile);
```

The issue I'm having pertains to `edit-profile`. The GET method works fine, and the data handling for PUT works as well, but when I try to have the page redirect after nothing happens.

`getEditProfile` (this directs the user to the profile editor page, where they can edit their account information):

```js
  static async getEditProfile(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const user = await UsersAccessor.getRegisteredByUsername(Authorize.getUsername(req));
      
      res.render("edit_profile", {
        name: user.username,
        role: user.role,
        year: user.information.year,
        major: user.information.major,
        bio: user.information.bio,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return handleError(res, Errors[500].DataGET);
    }
  }
```

`edit_profile.js` (this handles the HTML (EJS) form submission as a PUT request, since HTML forms natively only support GET and POST):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const form = document.querySelector('form');

    form.addEventListener('submit', async function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get form data
        const formData = new FormData(form);

        // Convert form data to JSON
        const jsonData = {};
        formData.forEach((value, key) => {
            jsonData[key] = value;
        });

        try {
            // Make PUT request to update profile
            const response = await fetch(window.location.href, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            });

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to update profile');
            }

            window.location.href = '/profile';

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

`putEditProfile` (this calls `updateUser()` to edit the account data, and attempts to redirect the user back to their profile page, but instead it stays on the profile editor page):

```js
  static async putEditProfile(req, res, next) {
    try {
      // Update the user information
      const updatedUser = {
        username: req.body.name,
        role: req.body.role,
        information: {
          year: req.body.year,
          major: req.body.major,
          bio: req.body.bio,
          image: req.body.image,
        },
      };
  
      // Update the password if provided (might be a nifty feature for the future)
      if (req.body.password) {
        updatedUser.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
      }

      // Update the user in the database
      const updatedUserData = await UsersAccessor.updateUser(updatedUser);
      if (!updatedUserData) {
        // Handle case where the user is not found
        return handleError(res, Errors[404].UserNotFound);
      }

      res.redirect("/profile");
    } catch (e) {;
      console.log(e);
      return handleError(res, Errors[500].DataPUT);
    }
  }
```

How should I handle the page redirection at the end? I already tried a lot of different strategies and research but nothing seems to work for some reason. Docker gives a status code of 302.

I expected the page to redirect to /profile following the put request.

Comment: Well, `window.location.href = '/profile'` is definitely going to redirect you.  Is that line of code getting executed?  You can tell by using the devtools debugger and stepping through your form submit handler.  Also check the console for errors.